# Jquery / Javascript - Turn <br> inside div to line break?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have little problem after sanitizing the content. I'm using laravel 4 and it's {{{ }}} way to sanitize user input when printing it out in view. However I'd like to allow br tags so users could use it as a line break

I did try few examples which I found from stackoverflow but they did not work.
such as:

```
$('.myclass').html().replace(/(<br \/>)+/g, "\n");
```

but it has no effect.

So basically I have

```
<div class="myclass">
<h3>this is <br> description</h3>
</div>
```

And what I see is:

```
this is <br> description
```

And I would need to br tag to simply make a line break instead of br tag showing up in text. Any help how to do this with jquery / javascript?

UPDATE:
When I look the page source I see:

```
<h3>this is &lt;br&gt; description</h3>
```

instead

Comment: UM, `\n` in a div is not going to be a line break.

Comment: I'm really new to jquery and just worked with those examples what I found. Could you let me know how can I create a line break instead?

Comment: Well if there is a <br> element, it should be a break. I am guessing that it is not exactly <br>. The line of code you have is just changing a string, it does nothing to the page.

Comment: It's sanitized output. So, yeah. Just text instead of <br> tag. That's why I would need jquery / javascript to pickup <br> and replace them with line break.

Comment: @epascarello it still breaks the line : https://jsfiddle.net/h0dzc21u/

Comment: @erkaner of course <br/> make a break. Changing it to `\n` would not.

Comment: @epascarello sorry I guess I was confused yesterday :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorted it out. This will help for those who might need it in the future:

```
$('h3').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var t = $this.text();
    $this.html(t.replace(/&lt;br\s*\/&gt;/g,'<br>'));
});
```

I used h3 instead of div class because using the class seems to remove the css from it.